# Matlab contourm function works with some contour intervals but not others

Tags: matlab, plot

In Matlab R2017a, contourm is behaving strangely -- given a set of plotting levels, it works when plotting some arrays but not others, even when those arrays differ only numerically. When it fails, I get an error "using adjustPolarVertices-->[n] polar vertices: too many", where n is usually 4 or 5. I have included an example of this puzzling behavior in the attached code. Adjusting the plotting levels to avoid this issue does sometimes work, but only sporadically and unpredictably.

Data file to load is at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0RXm6AmZUf3dmFrdG5pWVlzZjQ

```
%Load data
temp=load('samplevalues');
samplevalues1=temp.samplevalues1;samplevalues2=temp.samplevalues2;
samplelats=temp.samplelats;samplelons=temp.samplelons;

%Demonstrate that two arrays differ only in terms of numeric values, & are otherwise identical
figure(1);clf;imagesc(samplevalues1);colorbar;
figure(2);clf;imagesc(samplevalues2);colorbar;

%Contourm works for the first array...
levelstouse=-20:2:20;
figure(3);clf;contourm(samplelats,samplelons,samplevalues1,levelstouse,'Fill','on');
%...but not for the second
figure(4);clf;contourm(samplelats,samplelons,samplevalues2,levelstouse,'Fill','on');
```